# Custom font fails to show in iOS

Tags: ios, uifont

I 've a ttf file which symbols inside. It's found in iOS via the .plist file, it's enumerated in [UIFont familyNames] and it's loaded in [UIFont fontWithName].

However the label still shows normal text and numbers, where it should show symbols. Could it there be some incompatibility between my font and iOS?

Best regards.

Edit: I converted the fonts to OTF and it works. What could be the problem with TTF ?

Comment: How is it set to your label?

Comment: XCode 6.1 now lists custom fonts listed in the plist. Have you checked that  it's being shown?

Comment: Are you setting up your label in code or in a storyboard? Did you set the font object on the label, and verify it's not nil? Are you using regular or attributed strings? Can you upload a sample project that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: @AaronBrager In code, yes it's not nil, regular strings.

Comment: I 've changed it to OTF using an online tool and now it works ...